# cakePHP - Limit adds a random 100 at the end

Tags: cakephp, limit

I just want to limit my rows to 400, but it creates the query with '400,100' and causing issues.

Here is my code:

```
$this->paginate = array('limit' => 400,
                        'order' => array('MantisBugTable.sort_order' => 'ASC'),
                        'group' => '`MantisBugTable`.`id`',
                        'joins' => array(
                                      array(
                                        'alias' => 'MantisLastReadTicketTable',
                                        'table' => 'mantis_last_read_ticket_table',
                                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                                        'conditions' => array('`MantisLastReadTicketTable`.`ticket_id` = `MantisBugTable`.`id`', '`MantisLastReadTicketTable`.`user_id` = '.$userAdminInfo['UserAdmin']['id'])
                                      ),
                                      array(
                                        'alias' => 'MantisBugnoteTable',
                                        'table' => 'mantis_bugnote_table',
                                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                                        'conditions' => '`MantisBugnoteTable`.`bug_id` = `MantisBugTable`.`id`'
                                      )
                                  ),
                       'fields' => array('MantisBugTable.*', 'MantisLastReadTicketTable.*', 'COALESCE(MAX(`MantisBugnoteTable`.`last_modified`), `MantisBugTable`.`last_updated`, NULL) AS MantisBugnoteTable__LastModified')
                      );
```

But it spits it out with the limit having another '100' at the end:

```
SELECT `MantisBugTable`.*, `MantisLastReadTicketTable`.*, COALESCE(MAX(`MantisBugnoteTable`.`last_modified`), `MantisBugTable`.`last_updated`, NULL) AS MantisBugnoteTable__LastModified FROM `mantis_bug_table` AS `MantisBugTable` LEFT JOIN `mantis_last_read_ticket_table` AS `MantisLastReadTicketTable` ON (`MantisLastReadTicketTable`.`ticket_id` = `MantisBugTable`.`id` AND `MantisLastReadTicketTable`.`user_id` = 101) LEFT JOIN `mantis_bugnote_table` AS `MantisBugnoteTable` ON (`MantisBugnoteTable`.`bug_id` = `MantisBugTable`.`id`)  WHERE `MantisBugTable`.`handler_id` = 0 AND (NOT (`MantisBugTable`.`category_id` IN (10, 12)) AND NOT (`MantisBugTable`.`status` IN (80, 90)))  GROUP BY `MantisBugTable`.`id`  ORDER BY `MantisBugTable`.`sort_order` ASC  LIMIT 400, 100
```

Why do you think that's happening?

I've tried setting 'offset' => 0 but that didn't work.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score -3):

Nevermind, somehow had my cookies crossed up.

Comment: That's not an answer :|. Either answer the question, or delete it :)